# Combining angular and node.js in electron

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I'm trying to port an angular app that relies on a node.js api to electron. The API needs to be able to access local databases, so I am trying to combine the angular app and the node.js app in one project. I have it up and running as two seperate apps and have now ported the angular part to electron. Is there a way to also include the node.js part? Any guiding would be appreciated.

Comment: pretty much anything that runs in node.js should run alongside electron

Comment: I was banking on that as electron is based on node.js. This is my first time using electron and I can't find any documentation or example on how to implement this. Usualy I create two seperate apps, one in Angular for the frontend and one in node.js as the backend api.